# I'm unable to unwrap a mesh.obj export from rhino

Tags: mesh, uv

[image]I created a simple mesh-geometry (400 triangles) in rhino and want to unwrap it, because it will be build as metal structure (4x2meters in size).
Blender always unwraps it into single triangles.

Is it also possible to see the angles between the triangles? It would be easier for the modelmaker to pre-bend the metalsheets.

Comment: Is I understand your question, you meant a geometry unwrapping, not a texture.
It'll be convenient if you provide some screenshots.

Comment: Yes, it's just about the geometry. I posted a screenshot above

Comment: Please make sure that the geometry is actually connected by removing duplicate vertices *Vertex > Merge Vertices > By Distance*.